# Comparing two sets of three columns in Excel and highlight specific differences (screenshot of desired result included!)

Tags: excel

I've read around quite a bit and can't find this specific question addressed anywhere. Basically, I have a spreadsheet with two groups of three columns which I want to compare for differences, and conditionally format where necessary.

For instance:

```
Expected                           Found
Port | Protocol | Process          Port | Protocol | Process
23     tcp        telnet           23     tcp        telnet
25     tcp        smtpd            25     tcp        foo
80     tcp        httpd            80     udp        bar
161    udp        snmpd
```

I found a tool called Kaleidoscope that does a great job of this, and actually produces the result I'm looking for:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to use Excel conditional formatting to replicate this result?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, do you want to compare the same cell in each table, or the protocol/process for a port in each table?

Comment: Good question, I wasn't clear on that. I want to key in on the ports, then check the protocol/process for each and point out any differences. Also, the example above doesn't account for this, but there are definitely situations where port numbers can be listed twice, each with a different protocol (tcp and udp). Any extras (ports in "expected" but not "found", and vice-versa) would need to be highlighted as well (like the example link). I hope this helps!

Comment: easy to highlight IDs that are not present in the other table - `=isna(match(this_row_id, range_of_all_ids_from_other_table, 0))` - not so easy for the other stuff since the IDs are not unique

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a custom conditional format formula:

[image: CondFormatExample]

Good Luck.

**EDIT/ADDITION**

You should be able to match up the tables spatially directly in excel with some simple vlookup columns. You just need to create an additional ID column for every port/protocal combination:

[image: Example2]

And then you can use the conditional formatting method described above to highlight mismatched cells.

Comment: And obviously you can do the vice versa of this as well if you want both groups to be highlighted.

Comment: see row numbers in the example, they don't align.